# fill controls of web user control from parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two web user control in one the grid view is showing the result and the other contains the simply textboxes and the dropdowns that are basically created to edit that gridview items

the aspx.cs page code is

```
GridView gView = PlaceHolder2.Controls[0].FindControl("grvBranches") as GridView;
int index = gView.SelectedIndex;

GridViewRow grd = gView.Rows[index];
Label lbl = (Label)grd.FindControl("lblID");

int rowid = 0;
int.TryParse(lbl.ToString(), out rowid);
```

In rowid i contains the id of that item which is selected

now i want to fill all the following items in webusercontrol

```
<div class="col2_form1">
 <div class="form1_bar1">
    <div class="form1_txt1_div">
        <asp:Label ID="lblBranchName" runat="server" Text="Branch Name">
        </asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txtfield_div">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBranchName" class="form1_TxtField" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txt2_div">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVBranchName" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic"
            ValidationGroup="Save" ControlToValidate="txtBranchName" runat="server" />
        <%--  <asp:Label Text="Error" ID="lblBranchNameError" runat="server" />--%>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form1_bar2">
    <div class="form1_txt1_div">
        <asp:Label Text=" Organization Name" ID="lblOrganizationName" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txtfield_div">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrganization" CssClass="form1_TxtField" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txt2_div">
        <%--<asp:Label Text="Error" ID="lblOrganizationNameError" runat="server" />--%>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" form1_bar1">
    <div class="form1_txt1_div ">
        <asp:Label Text="Address Line1" ID="lblAddresLine1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class=" form1_txtfield_div">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddresLine1" CssClass="form1_TxtField" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txt2_div ">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Save"
            ControlToValidate="txtAddresLine1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" form1_bar2">
    <div class="form1_txt1_div ">
        <asp:Label Text="Address Line2" ID="lblAddresLine2" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txtfield_div ">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddresLine2" CssClass="form1_TxtField" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txt2_div ">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form1_bar1 ">
    <div class="form1_txt1_div">
        <asp:Label Text="Country" ID="lblCountry" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txtfield_div " style="float: left;">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form1_TxtField" runat="server"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class=" form1_txt2_div">
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" form1_bar2">
    <div class="form1_txt1_div ">
        <asp:Label Text="State" ID="lblState" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txtfield_div ">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form1_TxtField" runat="server"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txt2_div ">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form1_bar1 ">
    <div class="form1_txt1_div ">
        <asp:Label Text="City" ID="lblCity" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txtfield_div ">
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form1_TxtField" ID="ddlCity">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txt2_div ">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form1_bar2 ">
    <div class="form1_txt1_div ">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txtfield_div">
        <asp:Button Text="Save" Width="100px" runat="server" ID="btnSave" ValidationGroup="Save"
            OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </div>
    <div class="form1_txt2_div">
        <asp:Label Text="" ID="lblMsg" Visible="false" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

i have a property on the webusercontrol as

```
public string ABC_DEF
{
   set  {   txtABC.Text = value;       }
   get  {   return txtABC.Text;       }
}
```

and on the parent page i.e on the aspx page i call it as

```
if (ViewState["controlname"] != null)
{
  PlaceHolder pl = MainPanel.FindControl(ViewState["controlname"].ToString()) as PlaceHolder;
  pl.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
}
Control uc = (Control) Page.LoadControl("~/usercontrols/control_forms/branch_aspx_form.ascx");

ViewState["path"] = "~/usercontrols/control_forms/branch_aspx_form.ascx";
ViewState["controlname"] = "PlaceHolder1";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);


branch_view[] branch_to_edit = EntityService.ServiceInstance.GetBranchByBranchID(row_id);

foreach (branch_view item in branch_to_edit)
{
       usercontrols.control_forms.branch_aspx_form branch_control = 
                 new usercontrols.control_forms.branch_aspx_form();
      branch_control.ABC_DEF = " hello";  // Call property here
}
```

thanks 
Gurbax

Comment: Is there any special reason why you created a user control to update items?You can easily achieve this with a details view control

Comment: @Denys Wessels  yes i have to do this by user control

Comment: Hi Gurbax,I'd like to help you.Could you please specify exactly which part are you having trouble with?I understand that you are able to get the id of the selected row from the gridview.Do you need help retrieving the data from the database for the selected id or do you need help populating the user control with the retrieved data?

Comment: @DenysWessels my problem is that i have all the data from database for that seleted row but know the problem is how can i add this data to a different user control's fields i.e how to access the controls of the web user control on the parent aspx page so that i can assign the value to them..

Answer (score 1):

In your user control .ascx file create properties for each of the fields you need to be pulled onto the user control,

Then you can simply access them from the .aspx page by specifying the UserControlId.Property syntax like so:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return txtName.Text; }
    set { txtName.Text = value; }
}

public string Surname
{
    get { return txtSurname.Text; }
    set { txtSurname.Text = value; }
}
```

On the .aspx page the properties can be accessed like this:

```
protected void PopulateUserControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userControlName.Name = "Bob";
    userControlName.Surname = "The Builder";
}
```

Comment: when i apply this code the null refrence exception occur when i set the value of the property    set { txtName.Text = value; }
}  
from where i am using this proerty the value passed by me is correct i.e not null

Comment: Hi Gurbax, could you please ammend your question and provide some code.It's very diffuclt to analyse an issue like this without knowing exactly how you implemented the proposed solution in your code.Alternatively you can create a new question regarding the null reference exception

Comment: @ Denys Wessels please read the last lines of question i had edit the question